# Persisting Objects containing Objects with spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, naming-conventions, spring-data, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

Below is a follow-up question to [Question 13832188](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832188):

I'm using `spring-data-mongodb` version `1.1.1.RELEASE`.  I am able to persist an object if all the member variables are primitive types, even if the names of the `@PersistenceConstructor` arguments don't match exactly the names of the member variables by using the `@Field` and `@Value` annotations.

However, I get a `MappingInstantiationException` when I try to persist objects that contain other objects. My questions:

- Is this a bug in `spring-data-mongodb` or am I doing something wrong?
- What needs to change so that I can properly persist objects containing objects?

.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.recorder.TestRecorder2$ObjectContainer]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:209)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1820)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1542)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(MongoTemplate.java:1064)
    at com.recorder.TestRecorder2.testObjectContainer(RecorderTest2.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.recorder.TestRecorder2$ObjectContainer]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:75)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 35 more
```

My `PrimitiveContainer` and `ObjectContainer` classes are listed below:

```
@Document
class PrimitiveContainer {

    @Field("property") 
    private final int m_property;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public PrimitiveContainer(@Value("#root.property") int a_property) {
        m_property = a_property;
    }

    public int property() {
        return m_property;
    }
}

@Document
class ObjectContainer {

    @Field("property") 
    private final PrimitiveContainer m_property;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public ObjectContainer(@Value("#root.property") PrimitiveContainer a_property) {
        m_property = a_property;
    }

    public PrimitiveContainer property() {
        return m_property;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE: ** Curiously, changing the string in the `@Field` annotation to something other than "property" or removing the `@Field` annotation entirely for the `ObjectContainer` `m_property` allows spring-data-mongo-db to property re-instantiate my persisted `ObjectContainer` class.  I don't understand why this works. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are the source documents look like? I.e. what does the document look like inside the database?

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("50ca271c4566a2b08f2d667a"), "_class" : "com.recorder.TestRecorder2$ObjectContainer", "property" : { "property" : 100 } }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have found a bug. The value resulting from the first Spel expression evaluation is a `DBObject` and not actually translated into the parameter type. I've already have some code here locally that fixes that. Would you mind creating a ticket against Spring Data MongoDB to file this as a bug?

Comment: I've created [DATAMONGO-592](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-592) to track this issue.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I also found that I can't property persist objects that contain primitive arrays.  Is the bug that's preventing me from properly persisting objects that contain objects the same bug that's preventing me from properly persisting objects containing primitive arrays?  See the details of the array issue in [StackOverflow 13884637](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884637)