# Why do I get a "No property node found on entity class … to bind constructor parameter to!" with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Trying to use JodaTime's `LocalDate` with Spring Data MongoDB and Spring 4 but I am getting the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property node found on entity class com.th.model.Price to bind constructor parameter to!] with root cause
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property node found on entity class com.th.model.Price to bind constructor parameter to!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2121)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1805)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1611)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:535)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:526)
    at com.th.model.Company.getPrices(Company.java:255)
    at com.th.controller.Home.getPrices(Home.java:32)
    …
```

Here my configuration:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="th" host="localhost"/>

<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
    <mongo:converter>
        <bean class="com.th.tool.MongoDBConverters.DateToLocalDateConverter"/>
    </mongo:converter>
    <mongo:converter>
        <bean class="com.th.tool.MongoDBConverters.LocalDateToDateConverter"/>
    </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>


<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
</bean>
```

---

```
public class MongoDBConverters {

    public static class DateToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDate> {

        @Override
        public LocalDate convert(Date source) {
            return source == null ? null : LocalDate.fromDateFields(source);
        }
    }

    public static class LocalDateToDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, Date> {

        @Override
        public Date convert(LocalDate source) {
            return source == null ? null : source.toDate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the inner classes static...

Comment: If I do it I get another exception: No property node found on entity class com.th.model.Price to bind constructor parameter to. (the question is now updated)

Comment: That is completely unrelated and warrants a new question...

Comment: As of version 1.5 of Spring Data MongoDB you don't need any custom converters for JodaTime types. We now support those out of the box.

Comment: Strange because I use spring-data-mongodb 1.6.1

Comment: Your code was fine, all you needed was explicit default constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently I can't have a constructor like this:

```
public Price(String companyId, JsonNode node) {
        this.companyId = companyId;

        if(node != null) {
            this.date = Tools.getLocalDate(node.get("Date").getTextValue());
            this.closePrice = Double.parseDouble(node.get("Close").getTextValue());
            this.volume = Double.parseDouble(node.get("Volume").getTextValue());
        }
}
```

A normal one with direct assignment work:

```
public Price(String companyId, LocalDate date, double closePrice, double volume) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
    this.date = date;
    this.closePrice = closePrice;
    this.volume = volume;
}
```

Comment: That's correct. `JsonNode` is a Jackson type I assume. Spring Data MongoDB does have anything to do with Jackson. The mechanics of constructor parameter resolution is described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13834796/18122).

Answer (score 4):

You have to make your inner classes `static` at the moment they require an instance of the enclosing class `MongoDBConverters` to be available before the object can be constructed. Making this class `static` doesn't require that.

```
public class MongoDBConverters {
    public static class DateToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDate> {
        @Override
        public LocalDate convert(Date source) {
            return source == null ? null : LocalDate.fromDateFields(source);
        }
    }

    public static class LocalDateToDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, Date> {
        @Override
        public Date convert(LocalDate source) {
            return source == null ? null : source.toDate();
        }
    }
}
```

For more info check [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class).